# Pandas: Convert single row in data frame to a list with multiple dimensions

Tags: python, pandas

For simplicity sake, I have a two data frames which looks like this:

```
Df1
name year1 year2 year3
Eric 2019  2002  2008
Lana 2014  2018  2019

Df2
name year1 year2 year3
Sam  2017  2008  2003
Mary 2011  2010  2009
```

where 'name' is the index for each.

I want only the last row of each data frame to give me an output like this for example:

```
last_row_of_df = [[Lana], [2014], [2018], [2019]]
```

Because, if I iterate through dataframes, I can append a new list called 'all_last_rows' to look like this:

```
all_list_rows = [[[Lana], [2014], [2018], [2019]] , [[Mary], [2011], [2010], [2009]]]
```

and in return give me a new data frame to look like this. But how do I do it?

```
name year1 year2 year3
Lana 2014  2018  2019
Mary 2011  2010  2009
```

I would really appreciate the help.

Notes: what I can't change is the fact that I will most definitely have several data frames, and I will definitely have to perform an iteration to get through all individual data frames
to produce a new data frame, that will look like this

[the html output for the new data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMiC5.png)
Is there a way to auto-correct the values within the table to actually be displayed as ints or NaN, not [int] or [NaN]. Because at the bottom of the table, I want to perform calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.concat([x.iloc[[-1]] for x in [Df1, Df2]], ignore_index=True)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.concat([x.tail(1) for x in [Df1, Df2]], ignore_index=True)
```

EDIT:

```
out = []
for df in dfs:
    #some code
    out.append(df.iloc[[-1]])

df = pd.concat(out, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. I can only get a new dataframe when running a specific fucntion. Sorry for not making that clear. So I don't have all 32 data frames immediately, I need to get the first df, then append the list/newdf, then get the second df, and append the list/newdf....

Comment: Thank you yes both these solutions are working. If I have a follow up question, should i post it here?

Comment: @LlewellynHattingh - Can you try `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str[0])` ?

Comment: @LlewellynHattingh - If not working try `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('[]'))`

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```py
last_row_of_df = [Df1.index[-1]] + list(Df1.iloc[-1,:])
last_row_of_df = [[item] for item in last_row_of_df]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
last_row_of_df = list(my_data.iloc[-1, :])
last_row_of_df = [item for item in last_row_of_df]
```

was actually what got it looking as expected. Although no value is an integer which is annoying